# Solr - Enriching the TermsComponent answer

Tags: search, solr, lucene, websphere-commerce

I'm using Solr 3.5.0 (with WebSphere Commerce). While performing a search, commerce use the suggestion tool to suggest (auto-complete) search terms regarding the letters already typed on the search box.

Currently WebSphere Commerce is using the Solr's TermsComponent. But one of my new requirement is to be abble to enrich the list of suggested terms.

Do you know is there is any way to do that by creating a plain text dictionary, using an other  solr component, ... ?

Thanks for reading,
and for your help.

Regards,
Dekx.

Answer (score 1):

I think a plain-text dictionary probably wouldn't be a usable data source (even if you could use it, search linearly through a plain-text file would probably be too slow).  If you create an index from you dictionary, you could probably incorporate it in the TermsComponent as a shard (see the [TermsComponent documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent), under the heading "Distributed Search Support").

I don't believe TermsComponent supports searching multiple fields, so you'll want to make sure the same field name is used for the terms in the dictionary that you want to use (that is, if you are looking at the "name" field in the index, then create a "name" field in your indexed dictionary as well, rather than a "dictionaryentry" field)

Just to my mind, though, I fail to understand what the value this would be.  Generally, it's intended to look at the terms available in the index on that field.  "Enriching" it with more data, would just be providing suggestions that it won't actually be able to find when searching.  Of course, I don't really know about your search implementation, but in most cases, that would certainly be my thought.

Comment: You're right. Parsing plain text is not optimized. But I were expected something like a plain text dictionary that Solr will Index to enrich the TermComponent index.